# CSS first-child not working as expected

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am using the following CSS to try and remove the left-border on the first child div of any element with the class called, "tblRow"

```css
.tblRow div:first-child{
    border-left: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="tbl">
  <div class="tblRow">
    <div class="tblCell">Lower limit QTY</div>
    <div class="tblCell">Upper Limit</div>
    <div class="tblCell">Discount</div>
  </div>
  <div class="tblRow">
    <div class="tblCell">1</div>
    <div class="tblCell">5</div>
    <div class="tblCell">25%</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This only removes the left-border from the first child div in the first row. It does not remove it in the second row. Any ideas?

Comment: That should work. It may be a specificity thing though. Can you post your style that adds the border-left?

Comment: It works fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/SFRTj/1/

Comment: And [here, too: http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/E397e/](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/E397e/).

Comment: That looks like tabular data being stuffed inappropriately into div tags.

Comment: I really could not find the problem or conflict, so I took another suggestion. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I generally only use the :first-child and :nth-child psuedo selectors when I have little or no control over the elements or they are populated dynamically where I cannot rely on an order.  Additionally, since :nth-child is CSS3, you can't rely on complete browser compatibility. If you can do without this psuedo selector, my advise is to create a secondary class for this purpose.

```
.tblCell.firstCell{
border-left: none;
}

<div class="tbl">
  <div class="tblRow">
    <div class="tblCell firstCell">Lower limit QTY</div>
    <div class="tblCell">Upper Limit</div>
    <div class="tblCell">Discount</div>
  </div>
  <div class="tblRow">
    <div class="tblCell firstCell">1</div>
    <div class="tblCell">5</div>
    <div class="tblCell">25%</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work on the fiddle, so you probably have a (hidden) text node somewhere there. Therefore I suggest using `.tblRow div:first-of-type { ... }`, if possible from browser support point-of-view.

Comment: A text node, with the exception of `:empty`, doesn't affect CSS; especially since only elements will matched by the `:first-child` pseudo-selector. There may be another element, though.